# GTK FileChooserDialog in Ruby doesn't close window

Tags: ruby, gtk

When I run the following ruby code in a bash terminal (Ubuntu 14.04, ruby 1.9.3),
folder_test works fine, but my_test shows a strange behaviour:
It doesn't close the gtk dialog window when I choose a folder from
bookmarks and the focus remains on the dialog window instead of returning to the terminal
although the chosen folder has been correctly reported to the terminal.
What went wrong and how can I enforce the closing of the dialog window?

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*- 
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'gtk3'

def get_folder(folder)  
  a=''     
  Dir.chdir(File.expand_path(folder)) {
  dialog = Gtk::FileChooserDialog.new(
    :title => "Choose folder", :parent => nil, 
    :action => :select_folder, 
    :buttons => [[Gtk::Stock::OPEN, Gtk::ResponseType::ACCEPT], [Gtk::Stock::CANCEL, Gtk::ResponseType::CANCEL]])
  if dialog.run == Gtk::ResponseType::ACCEPT
    a=dialog.filename
  end
  dialog.destroy }
  return a 
end

def folder_test
  b=get_folder("/home")
  if b=="/home" 
    puts "No folder chosen"
    exit
  end
  puts "#{b} was choosen."
end

def my_test
  while true do
    folder_test
    puts "Another folder?(y/n)"
    answer=gets.chomp.downcase
    unless answer=='y'
      exit
    end
  end  
end

#folder_test
my_test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code after `dialog.destroy`:

```
while Gtk.events_pending?
  Gtk.main_iteration
end
```

For example:

```
  if dialog.run == Gtk::ResponseType::ACCEPT
    a=dialog.filename
  end
  dialog.destroy
  while Gtk.events_pending?
    Gtk.main_iteration
  end
  }
  return a
end
```

diff:

```
@@ -13,7 +13,11 @@ def get_folder(folder)
   if dialog.run == Gtk::ResponseType::ACCEPT
     a=dialog.filename
   end 
-  dialog.destroy }
+  dialog.destroy
+  while Gtk.events_pending?
+    Gtk.main_iteration
+  end 
+  }
   return a
 end
```

Comment: Yes, this closes the dialog window reliably. Thank you. Now - after that - when in my_test the FileChooserDialog is called for the second time it doesn't get the focus but stays in the backgroung. Any suggestions how to fix that?

Comment: Ummm... One of a solution is calling as an external command with the get_folder method in a separate file. For example: `b=\`ruby ./get_folder.rb "/home"\``

Comment: Well, this doesn't work for me, but luckily when I start my original programm via a .desktop file in Ubuntu the problem is gone. So its all ok and thanks again for your help.